# How can I calculate integrated water vapor transport (IVT) in NCL, R or Python?

Tags: netcdf, water-vapour, r

I have netcdf (ERA5) file  (u and v component of wind and specific humidity) between years 1970-2022. Are there any package or script documentation about that?

Comment: Hello Skyriver, are you having trouble opening/reading the netcdf file or are you looking for a formula to use?  Please provide more detail about the specific issue you are having.